# Efficient (linear time) nested queries in SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb, pivot, query-optimization, gaps-and-islands

From this table:

### events

| id | event_date | event_score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2020-04-10 |  |
| 13 | 2020-04-11 |  |
| 13 | 2020-04-14 | 8 |
| 13 | 2020-04-13 | 6 |
| 12 | 2020-04-15 |  |
| 14 | 2020-04-16 |  |
| 14 | 2020-04-17 |  |
| 14 | 2020-04-18 | 11 |
| 14 | 2020-04-19 |  |
| 14 | 2020-04-20 |  |
| 14 | 2020-04-22 |  |
| 12 | 2020-04-25 |  |
| 14 | 2020-04-30 |  |

I'm trying to get this result

### results

| id | first_score | last_score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 |  |  |
| 13 | 6 | 8 |
| 14 | 11 | 11 |

One way to do that is through this query:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT id,
    (
        SELECT event_score
        FROM events AS subquery
        WHERE final_table.id=subquery.id
        AND event_score IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY event_date
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS `first score`,
    (
        SELECT event_score
        FROM events AS subquery
        WHERE final_table.id=subquery.id
        AND event_score IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY event_date DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS `last score`
FROM sensors.events as final_table
```

but I suspect this takes quadratic time O(n*n) to compute.  I know it can be done in linear time O(n) with Python but does anyone know how to do it in linear time with SQL?

The table is in MariaDB/MySQL

Comment: Do you have table with one row per `id`?

Comment: Check your guesses first, look at the execution plan by using `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: @HyperActive . . . Unless the data is already sorted, then you need to take the sort time into account in Python.  If it is sorted, then it doesn't correspond to a SQL table (which is be definition unsorted).

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MariaDB 10.2.2 or higher, you could address this as a gaps-and-islands problem. The idea is to count how many non-`null` values appear on the preceding and following rows. We can then filter on the first non-null value in both directions, using conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
    max(case when grp_asc  = 1 then event_score end) as first_score,
    max(case when grp_desc = 1 then event_score end) as last_score
from (
    select e.*,
        count(event_score) over(partition by id order by event_score     ) as grp_asc,
        count(event_score) over(partition by id order by event_score desc) as grp_desc
    from events e
) e
group by id
order by id
```

I cannot assess the time complexity of this algorithm, but I would suspect that this should run faster than your original query, that requires executing two subqueries per distinct `id`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=49cf5fdf73e69982059ede2dd8e6edc5)**:

```
id | first_score | last_score
-: | ----------: | ---------:
12 |        null |       null
13 |           6 |          8
14 |          11 |         11
```

Answer (score 1):

With a an index on `(id, event_date, event_sore)`, then this should be quite fast:

```
SELECT id,
       (SELECT event_score
        FROM events AS subquery
        WHERE final_table.id = subquery.id AND event_score IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY event_date
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS `first score`,
       (SELECT event_score
        FROM events AS subquery
        WHERE final_table.id=subquery.id AND event_score IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY event_date DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS `last score`
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT e.id
      FROM sensors.events e
     ) as final_table;
```

Note that this moves the `SELECT DISTINCT` to a subquery.  This is to ensure that MariaDB does not actually use a "distinct" algorithm for the `SELECT DISTINCT` -- the other columns would probably cause that to happen.

However, this is O(n log n) because the subqueries need to sort a small amount of data for each `id` -- as well as using an index to get to the right place.

I cannot think of a way to do this O(n) in SQL.  I'm pretty sure the following constructs are all O(n log n):

- Using an index for each row.
- Sorting any portion of the data.
- Using any window function with an `order by` -- although this might be true if there is just the right index.

But, SQL queries are still fast, particularly with indexes.